# .next() and .addClass() not working in jquery

Tags: jquery

Hello friends following is my code

HTML

```
 <ul>
    <li>
    <div class="input"><input name="" type="checkbox" value="" id="a"/></div>
    <div >Name of the survey goes here | 35 Points - <span>Begin Survey</span></div> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

Jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#a').click(function(){

    $(this).next('div').addClass('.check_clicked');

    })
})
</script>
```

CSS

```
.check_clicked
{
    text-decoration:line-through;
    color:#b6a7a7;
}
```

I just want to if check box value checked then class `.check_clicked` should apply on next div

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.next()` accesses the next sibling. However, your `#a` element does not have one.

What you want is `$(this).parent().next()`

You also need to remove the `.` in the class name - `addClass()` only accepts classes so it does not need a `.` in front of the class name.

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DqLRc/
If unchecking the checkbox should not remove the class again, simply keep `addClass` instad of my `toggleClass` call.

Comment: Great - please do not forget to accept the answer once the 15-minute delay is over.